# How to cut the file into two fields in shell?

Tags: shell, cut

Please unzip the file which download from :
http://s.yunio.com/MT3r2x
The data format is :

```
   ‘x + y’                         x plus y                                  
   ‘x - y’                         x minus y                                 
   ‘x*y’                           juxtapose x and y                         
   ‘x/y’                           x forwardslash y                          
   ‘x %+-% y’                      x plus or minus y
```

For

```
cut -c 1-43   maths.txt
```

The output is :

```
   ‘x + y’                         
   ‘x - y’                         
   ‘x*y’                           
   ‘x/y’                           
   ‘x %+-% y’
```

For

```
cut -c 44-    maths.txt
```

The output is :

```
x plus y                                
x minus y                               
juxtapose x and y                       
x forwardslash y                        
x plus or minus y
```

The two fields are  what i want to get.

Why i can't use the following command to cut it into two fields?
`cut -d' ' -f2  maths.txt`  or  `cut -d'        ' -f2 maths.txt(ctrl+v+tab)`  can do neither.

Comment: Please provide a few sample lines

Comment: Not sure exactly what you have, what you want and what you are getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `cut -d' ' -f2  maths.txt`  or  `cut -d'        ' -f2 maths.txt(ctrl+v+tab)`  are working. The problem is that they print the text in each line after first space and before second one. As you have a lot of spaces, it just shows spaces.

What you can do is to cat the original one and pipe it using `col` like this:

```
cat maths.txt | col | cut -d$'\t' -f1 # first col 
cat maths.txt | col | cut -d$'\t' -f2 # second col
```

Answer (score 0):

`cut` counts the number of fields irrespective of the previous field. So unline awk, 3 consecutive spaces means 3 fields. So try to use `cut -d' ' -f-42 maths.txt` or the other way round, you should see it taking effect. `-f2` here is just the absolute 2nd field which should be white space. `-f-42` is to print everything till 42nd field, and `-f43-` is print everything from 43rd field.